# How do you test a Subaru Ignitor?

Tags: subaru, svx

I'm working to install an EG33 H6 Subaru motor out of a 92 SVX into an Impreza. I'm having issues with it starting. I'm getting nothing at all as far as spark from the coils. I'm systematically eliminating possible issues and the latest place I've come to is testing the ignitor.

Q: **How do you positively test the ignitor to ensure it is working properly?** (Other than of course the fateful: *Is the engine running?* :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first test is power and ground to the igniter.  If these are correct then the command signals are checked next.

I test these signals with an an oscilloscope.  One channel on the input wire from the PCM. The other lead goes on the output line to the coil. Subaru usually uses a 12 volt square wave from the PCM to the igniter. The output from the igniter to the coils is also a 12v square wave. According to service information each coil on this engine is driven separately from the PCM through the igniter to the a coil. Set the scope to -1 volt to 15 volt scale and time scale fast enough to capture two fire commands per second at engine cranking speed. Look for clean square wave.

If a square wave is present from the PCM but not out from it to the coils then the igniter has failed. If there is a good square wave out to the coil then the problem is with the coil. If there is no signal from the PCM then look to PCM inputs, especially the rotation sensors.

Comment: How can I check the ignitor without a scope? Also, which side is in from the ECU and out to the coils? They are marked "I" and "E" with six on each side.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  A multimeter with a hertz frequency counter function sometimes works. The frequency per coil will be very low, under 5 counts per second.   The inputs are the light blue with stripe wires and the outs are green with stripes.  The wiring diagram I have is fuzzy and not suitable for posting here.